# VBA Replace Exact Match

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code - but currently it doesn't find exact match.
EG if it finds no in not completed - it will add not completed.
How to I make them exact match?

```
Columns("E").Replace What:="YES", Replacement:="Completed"
Columns("E").Replace What:="No", Replacement:="Not Completed"
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a slightly different variation like so:

```
    Columns("E").Replace What:="YES", Replacement:="Completed", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False
    Columns("E").Replace What:="No", Replacement:="Not Completed", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False
```

See documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Replace

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]